# Is it possible to create named volume via Dockerfile during docker build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have multiple images with ruby apps. I want to share installed gems. Is it possible to create named volume with folder where gems install? What is the right way to arrange it?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem by creating an image where I install/update all my gems as a volume. You will need following in Dockerfile for gems container:

```
VOLUME /PATH/TO/GEMS
```

then importing these gems in all the other containers using shared volumes:

```
docker run --volumes-from CONTAINER_WITH_GEMS --name CONTAINER_NAME IMAGE
```

Multiple containers can also share one or more data volumes. However, multiple containers writing to a single shared volume can cause data corruption. Given this  if you can make sure your applications are designed to write to shared data stores we can solve this other way around as well.

Comment: I guess you mean Data Only Container. Am I right? I would use Data Volume if it's possible. 

I understood VOLUME directive wrong. I thought it creates volume during an image building but now I understand it create volume during running an container only.

Comment: Yes. Actually when you mark a path as volume and add some content to it. The content can be accessed by other containers by importing the volumes.  That is what I was referring to. Briefly, create image with gems installed at a volume, create a container (cont1) from this image, spawn a new container exporting volumes from cont1 then you will be able to access the gems.  Let me know if you want any sample for this.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. In Dockerfile you can't specify a named volume.

But you can specify a container folder to be created as a volume regardless the parameters in docker run. You use the VOLUME directive for it.

But you must tell users to map their local directory to the volume. You can distribute a docker-compose.yml file to your users to easy the process.